# How to pass dynamic list of conditions in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of filter conditions for a spark sql query in the form of

```
Map<String, List<String>> conditions
```

Lets say that the initial dataset is

```
Dataset<Row> dataSet
```

I want to use each entry in the map lets say (StringA, ListA), (StringB, ListB)... and so on, in the filter where each entry will be an OR condition

```
(col("my_col1").equals("StringA").and(col("my_col2").isInCollection(ListA)))

OR

(col("my_col1").equals("StringB").and(col("my_col2").isInCollection(ListB)))

OR

(col("my_col1").equals("StringC").and(col("my_col2").isInCollection(ListC)))
....
```

The dataset is a Cassandra table with (my_col1, my_col2) as the partition key.

I don't expect to have more than 5-6 entries in the map

Answer (score 1):

use isin

```
d.filter(col("value").isin(desiredThings: _*))
```

but if you really want to foldLeft you have to provide the base condition

```
d.filter(desiredThings.foldLeft(lit(false))(
(acc, x) => (acc || col("value") === (x)))
)
```

Alternatively, to use with filter or where, you can generate a SQL expression using:

```
val filterExpr = desiredThings.map( v => s"value = $v").mkString(" or ")
```

And then use it like

```
d.filter(filterExpr).show
// or
d.where(filterExpr).show

//+-----+
//|value|
//+-----+
//|    1|
//|    3|
//+-----+
```